# Angular promise returning incorrect data from JSON API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, api

**Update: 02/12/2015**
As mentioned in the comments this was an issue with the object being modified by an Angular module.  I was able to track this down using `toJSON` as mentioned below.

I have recently ran into an issue that has be quite boggled. I have a service that is request data from an api via `get` request. When looking on the network panel in Chrome developer tools the api returns the proper results but they are not show in the response from the angular request.

You can note the content section is missing items.  And Angular code:

**Angular Code**

```
function getPhotos(){
      return $http.get('/photo')
        .then(getPhotosComplete)
        .catch(function(err){
         //handle errors

        });
      function getPhotosComplete(res){
        //Showing incorrect response here
        console.log("getPhotosComplete", res);
        return res.data;
      }
    }
```

**From API**

`{
url: "https://dev.amazonaws.com/060a2a5f-8bb7-4ffa-aa7d-e715439271a3.jpg",
archive_name: "140809",
seedcount: 0,
viewcount: 0,
live: true,
current: false,
next: false,
createdAt: "2015-02-10T17:48:41.505Z",
updatedAt: "2015-02-12T04:11:02.239Z",
content: [
"Balloon",
"Apartment",
"Testing",
"Testing 2",
"Party",
"Inez"
],
id: "54da44790eb10b0f00b453a1"
}`

**Angular Scope / res.data in service**
`{
url: "https://dev.amazonaws.com/060a2a5f-8bb7-4ffa-aa7d-e715439271a3.jpg", seedcount: 0,
viewcount: 0,
live: true,
current: false,
next: false,
createdAt: "2015-02-10T17:48:41.505Z",
updatedAt: "2015-02-12T04:11:02.239Z",
content: Array[3]
0: "Balloon",
1: "Apartment",
2: "Party"
]`

Comment: If you are using non-minified Angular, you can debug into Angular's code to see how Angular transform your response. AFAIK, Angular would try to transform your response to JSON object. Maybe something went wrong there.

Comment: Are you really sure? Try logging with JSON.stringify to make sure it's not just a display artifact. `Array[3] 0: "Balloon", 1: "Apartment", 2: "Party" ]` looks very suspicious.since it's not even JSON

Comment: @JuanMendes - I am sure, it is just the object that is returned in console. I have also use batarang and logged in many places.

Comment: Agree with @JuanMendes, Try the response logging using either by angular.toJson() or JSON.stringify().

Comment: @JuanMendes - I have used your method. While the JSON is correct in the response the object is not updated with the proper values. Any ideas on cause of that?

Comment: @jnolte All I can say is that the object is likely being modified somewhere down the stack. You should use a debugger and step through the unminified code as Rebornix suggested.

Comment: @JuanMendes - Thanks you helped me get to the bottom of the issue. A module ended up modifying the object on the scope immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output from `angular.toJson()` is correct, but the `console.log` of the object is wrong, then it strongly suggests the object is being modified in the code somewhere after the call to `console.log`.

This is because `console.log` takes a reference to an object, and some time later it turns it into a string for output. I would class it as slightly evil behaviour, as it suggests the bug is before the call to `console.log`, while actually the issue after it. Hours can be wasted looking through the wrong code...

Comment: This fiddle may help explain what you mean with the `console.log` http://jsfiddle.net/mg1yu0fo/